# MongoDB Enforcing Complex constraints across documents in a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, atomic

Lets say I have documents in a collection called Users that look like this:

```
{
  name: 'vic', <-- unique index
  ownedItems: ['paperclip-1252', 'stapler-1337']
}
```

ownedItems is an array of the uniquely indexed identifiers in some other Items collection. Now, lets say I want to add an element to the ownedItems array, but I want to enforce the rule that: one cannot update the ownedItems array of a user in a way that results in more than one User document existing that contains the same item identifier in their ownedItems arrays.

That is to say, I want to execute:

```
db.Users.updateOne(
  { name: 'vic'}, 
  { $set: { 
      ownedItems: [
        'paperclip-1252', 
        'stapler-1337', 
        'notebook-42'
      ]
    } 
  })
```

... is only allowed to succeed if no other User document has an ownedItems array containing 'notebook-42' (or 'paperclip-1252', or 'stapler-1337').

I could do a query to check, do any users besides 'vic' have any of the items in the proposed ownedItems array, like so:

```
db.Users.find({
  $and: [
    { 
      ownedItems: { 
        $in: ['paperclip-1252', 'stapler-1337','notebook-42'] 
      } 
    },
    {
      name: { $ne: 'vic' }
    } 
  ]  
})
```

... and only proceed with the update if that returns no results. However whose to say that in the time between I get that answer, and when I execute my update, the answer hasn't changed (e.g. because someone else inserted 'notebook-42' into their ownedItems)?

How can I atomically execute that query then update the document based on the result? While I have described this using MongoDB CLI syntax, I will, rather be implementing this logic in a NodeJS application using the mongodb package, in case that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unique indexes are the only way I can think of that cross document constraints can be applied inside Mongodb, which happens to work in this case.

Create a unique index on `ownedItems`. Mongo will index on each set value rather than the set itself.

To allow duplicate empty arrays (ab)use the sort order of null and empty records going before populated arrays.

```
db.Users.createIndex({ ownedItems: 1 }, { 
  unique:1, 
  partialFilterExpression: { 
    ownedItems: { $gt: []  }
  }
})
```

Testing

```
db.Users.insert({name: 'vic', ownedItems: ['one','two']}) // Works

db.Users.insert({name: 'ted', ownedItems: ['one']}) // E11000 duplicate key
db.Users.insert({name: 'ted', ownedItems: ['two']}) // E11000 duplicate key
db.Users.insert({name: 'ted', ownedItems: ['one', 'three']}) // E11000 duplicate key

db.Users.insert({name: 'ted', ownedItems: ['three']}) // Works

db.Users.insert({name: 'ann', ownedItems: ['four','four']})  // E11000 duplicate key

db.Users.insert({name: 'jim', ownedItems: []}) 
db.Users.insert({name: 'pen', ownedItems: []}) // Works
```

If you need anything more complex you'll need to implement the logic in your app, including the transaction system if needed. Traditional RDBMS like Maria/Postgres have better support for more complex DB logic and transactions.

Comment: ah, that's great, I missed the subtlety that a unique index on an array field enforces uniqueness on the elements of the array across documents; it's not super clear from the mongo docs

Comment: ... but there's a problem, I just discovered, because of the description under "Unique Index and Missing Field" in the docs, two or more users cannot have ownedItems: [ ] or I get dup key: { : undefined } ... is there a way around that?

Comment: ... I'm going to try to use the guidance of "Partial Index with Unique Constraint"

Comment: ok that works, I just had to add a field for ownedItemsLength and maintain it so that I could add a partialFilterExpression: { ownedItemsLength: { $gte: 1 } } } to the unique constraint; thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: `partialFilterExpression: { ownedItems: { $gt: [] }}` should allow you to remove the tracking.

Comment: that's awesome, I wish I could give you _another_ upvote. How did you figure that gem out? I just tried it in the node REPL and it works there too (which of course is the same reason it works in Mongo): null > [ ] === false, [ ] > [ ] === false, [ 'anything' ] > [ ] === true... that is both crazy and awesome :-)

Comment: I'd like to claim it as my own by I'd guess it was picked up from someones stackoverflow answer along the way :)  If `partialFilterExpression` supported the normal filter syntax then it probably wouldn't need something so obscure.